# Google Sheets: How to make a stacked/aggregate chart

Tags: google-sheets, charts, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have made a bar chart which aggregates my data, but is there any way I can split each bar based on the data it is aggregating - similar to how a stacked bar chart would look?

Here is a bad artists impression (thick blue lines mine). The idea is that it's important to know from looking at the graph if I sold 5 at £1, or 1 at £5.

[image: What I want....]

Ideally this would work even if the price for each item is variable, but that is not essential (eg: if there is a 'hack' with hardcoding Apple = 3, I can live with that.)

I'm also fine inputting helper columns etc, within reason, but I would want to be able to easily continue to add things to the list on the left without having to add *new* helper columns each time (calculated ones are fine, of course.)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** With thanks to Kin Siang below, I ended up implementing a slightly modified version of their solution, which I am posting here for completeness.

I added a very large (but finite) number of helper columns to the right, with a formula in each cell which would look for the nth occurrence of the item in the main list (wrapped in an iferror to make the unused cells blank).

```
=iferror(index(FILTER($A:$B,$A:$A=$D2),E$1,2))
```

[image: Solution]

Theoretically it could run out of space one day, but I have made it suitably large that this should not be an issue. It has the advantage over the other solution that I do not need to sort or otherwise manipulate the input range and can continue trickling in data to the main list and have the chart automatically update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to display the chart in your case, however need some data transpose in order to do so, let me show you the example with dataset

Assuming this is your original data:

[image]

First sort the data by alphabet, and enter this formula in new column

```
=if(G39="",1,if(G40=G39,I39+1,if(G40<>G39,1)))
```

[image]

Next add new column for categorical purpose, by using concatenate function

```
="Price"&I40
```

[image]

In the transform data for chart purpose, enter this formula to split all price into different row, different column for different product

```
=sumifs($H$40:$H$47,$G$40:$G$47,$A41,$J$40:$J$47,B$40)
```

[image]

After that i select stack bar chart and ensure the price in under series, in case in 2*3 will have some problem to set price at series correctly, you can use 3*3 data create stack bar chart and update the data range again, it will work also

Here is the cute chart you expected, accept if help :)

[image]

*When certain fruit has less price record, it is advised to fill in 0, as the data table need in same column (see the orange price 3), although I didnot test if blank

Comment: Thanks very much for the response!

The issue I have with this method is that I need the data to come from a single long (and expanding) list, as I continuously import more data. There may be 100+/1000+ instances of some items by the time I'm finished.

Unless there's a way of dynamically generating the structure you use there (with potentially a very high number of columns) from that list, then it would be more work to maintain than is worth.

Is it possible to generate a similar graph but using the data in the format from my example?

Comment: I think it is possible to achieve with transpose function, let me think about, mind accept the answer first and I will try address your issue in another question, perhaps other may solve it earlier than me :)

Comment: I have given it a +1, but I specified I am looking for a solution that did not require adding new columns as the list of items grows, so this does not quite solve my issue.

Comment: In such case, it is impossible to achieve your chart with only two column, although it is possible to transform your data into pre-defined format for chart purpose

Comment: ok, you may see my edit answer, you can transpose your original data into specific form by using formula only, accept if help :)